# In Visual Studio C++ what is the equivalent of a delphi TPanel or alTop, alClient for organizing controls?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, delphi, mfc

I am trying to figure out what people use in visual studio c++ to organize their controls and align them. In delphi a TPanel is used and there is alignment features which are extremely useful. In visual studio c++ is the only way to organize your controls by writing lots of code to resize everything at run time?

A TPanel in delphi allows you to align left, right, client, top, bottom, and put controls in it with the panel as the parent control. I can not figure out how one does this in visual c++ unless you write a lot of code which kind of defeats the purpose if a visual development environment.

I suppose visual studio is not RAD so you can not compare it directly to delphi, but how do people organize their controls on dialogs without writing a lot of code in visual studio... are there some third party controls out there that emulate delphis TPanel? And does visual studio c++ have a way of emulating delphi`s alTop, alClient, alRight, etc. like seen in delphi TPanels?

Comment: C++ is a programming language. There is no GUI library as part of the standard. There are many GUI libraries available from C++, but they are outside C++. Which GUI library are you using?

Comment: I am asking about visual studio moreso than c++, I am specifying C++ because I am using the c++ portion of visual studio,  not visual basic, not .NET. I am creating a win32 gui app, or Mfc, which is included with visual studio in the c++ department of the program.

Comment: Visual Studio is an IDE that is capable of producing GUIs with many frameworks. That you are asking about MFC should be part of the question. Please edit. Both the text and the tags. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some third party libraries, but the Windows API, and hence MFC/Visual C++ does not have any native support for those things.  If you want something like that without any 3rd party libs, I would suggest you use Visual C# and WPF.  Dialogs in standard MFC or Windows API programs are layed out with each control getting a rectangular position and size.  There is the standard dialog editor, but it does not dynamically resize or re-layout controls when the dialog is resized.